# Verilog - Name is optional when instantiating primitive gates

Tags: digital-logic, verilog

Why is the name optional when instantiating primitive
gates, but not optional when defined modules are instantiated?

Example:

```
// Instantiate primitive gates
xor (S, x, y);
and (C, x, y);
endmodule
```

vs.

```
// Instantiate half adders
half_adder HA1 (S1, C1, x, y);
half_adder HA2 (S, C2, S1, z);
```

Answer (score 4):

Because a module of any use has identifiers declared inside that you may need to access, either from within your code, or externally for debugging (like a waveform dump). There is nothing inside a primitive for you to observe. You need an instance name to create a qualified path name.